# RegEx to match all characters between the last occuring upper case word and another word in a String

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I need to match all characters between the last occuring upper case word in a String and another word. Input Text:**The CLEVER fox JUMPED OVER the big and (Hole 2) wall in the night.**

RegEx Used :

```
(?<=\b[A-Z]+\s)(.+?)(?=\sin)
```

The above regex gives `fox JUMPED OVER the big and (Hole 2) wall`

**Expected Output:** `the big and (Hole 2) wall`

Can anyone crack this?

Comment: What if the word ("in") occurs more than once after the last upper case word?

Comment: It should match with the first occuring "in" after the last occuring UPPER CASE word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be the most effective solution, but it seems to work:

```
String text = "The CLEVER fox JUMPED OVER the big wall in the night.";
String regex = "(\\b[A-Z]+\\s)(?!.*\\b[A-Z]+\\b)(.+?)(\\sin)";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(text);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
}
```

It uses negative look-ahead to make sure there are no more upper-case words in the text before capturing the wanted data.

Comment: Thanks a ton. This works like a charm. Excuse me for my noobness in RegEx as I am trying to learn, but is there any way that I can get the second captured group as the output alone as that is my only desired output.

Comment: I think I got what I wanted. Here is the modified regex which gave me what I needed  (?<=(\b[A-Z]+\s)(?!.*\b[A-Z]+\b))(.+?)(?=\sin)

Comment: @immzi: Yes, I didn't realize you wanted that, but you got it right.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply exclude upper case characters in your second matching expression

`(?<=\b[A-Z]+\s)([^A-Z]+)(?=\sin)`

This will force the first part to match `The CLEVER fox JUMPED OVER`, the second matching expression will yield `the big wall` and the last one matches the only `in` sequence in your test sentence.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. This works. But if I add a word in between with single upper case alphabet.[updated the question] This regex fails. Any solution for this. Greatly appreciate your inputs

Comment: @immzi: My solution works for the adjusted text as well.

Comment: If you can have individual upper-case characters, negative look-ahead is the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
[A-Z][\s.](?!.*?[A-Z])(.*)\sin
```

Expl.: Find a capital letter followed by a white space, NOT followed by anything followed by a capital letter. Then capture anything up to, but not including, a space followed by the given word.

This captures the wanted part only.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
^.*(?:\b[A-Z]+\b)(.+?)(?=\sin)
```

**Explanation:**

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:^.*(?:\b[A-Z]+\b)(.+?)(?=\sin))

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                             and something that is not a word char
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [A-Z]+                   any character of: 'A' to 'Z' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                             and something that is not a word char
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .+?                      any character except \n (1 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    in                       'in'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I am sorry, but I dont seem to get the result with either of the two regexes that you gave.

Comment: @immzi: Strange, it works here. Are you geting the result in group 1?

Comment: Am getting no results

Comment: I did get the result by tweaking the regex given by @Keppil